# react router and meteor mongo

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I want to use React router but I have a problem with meteor mongo
I use Meteor 1.5.1
main.js:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    let translates = Translates.find().fetch();
    ReactDom.render(<App translates={translates}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
  });
});
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import AddTranslate from './AddTranslate';
import TranslateList from './TranslateList';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Firts text</p>
        <h1>Hello :D</h1>
        <TranslateList translates={this.props.translates}/>
        <AddTranslate/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

App.propTypes = {
  translates: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
```

I know, I need something like this:

```
export const history = createBrowserHistory({
  forceRefresh: true
});    

export const routes = (
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/beginner" component={Beginner}/>
      <Route path="/" component={App}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
);
```

and change:

```
ReactDom.render(<App translates={translates}/>, document.getElementById('app'));

ReactDom.render(<routes/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

but what with translates={translates}?

thanks for help :)

Comment: You might find https://themeteorchef.com/blog/introducing-pup helpful for learning react+meteor+react-router-dom

Comment: +1 for the link. The [createContainer](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-create-container#!) method described in the above link from Michel also gives you a good way of decoupling your react code from meteor code. Thus allowing you to to write even more reusable react components.

Comment: Thanks very much :D This link is great!